# Typing an array of instances of React components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I have a table component that receives an array of string/number arrays as a prop, so it takes a `rows` parameter typed like this:

```
type Row = (string | number)[];
```

However, some columns need to display a React component instead of a plain text / number.

How can I change the typings to make it work? I tried this:

```
type Row = (string | number | React.PureComponent | React.Component)[];
```

Comment: For reference, this question is/was under Featured Meta effect: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390301/would-a-note-about-preferred-pronouns-qualify-the-same-way-as-a-thank-you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are many options here that would work, some better than others depending on how you use them. I've been using `React.ReactNode` for specifying children, but you could probably use it for your use-case too.

```
type Row = (string | number | React.ReactNode)[];
```

`ReactNode` is quite flexible, since it is defined as:

```
type ReactNode = ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;
```

and `ReactChild` in turn, is defined as: `type ReactChild = ReactElement | ReactText;`

If you want it stricter, less flexible, try `ReactElement`.